# ToList returns a list with an unique null element

Tags: c#, linq

I'm running this LINQ code, but in the elements where the Options property should be an empty List, there is a List with one element, which is just 'null', any idea how to fix this?

```
 var metadata = from md in context.Metadata
                       join o in context.MetadataOptions on md.MetadataId equals o.MetadataId into op
                       from opts in op.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       group opts by md into ops
                       select new MetadataDTO
                       {
                           Enabled = ops.Key.Enabled,
                           Name = ops.Key.Name,
                           MetadataCategoryId = ops.Key.MetadataCategoryId,
                           MetadataId = ops.Key.MetadataId,
                           Id = ops.Key.Id,
                           Type = ops.Key.Type,
                           Options = ops.ToList()
                       };
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try `ops.FirstOrDefault().ToList()`. `ops` has type of `IGrouping`, you should change it to `IEnumerable` before using `ToList` method.

Comment: I suggest using the Extension-method syntax instead of the keyword syntax as it makes it clear what Linq is actually doing. Anyway you're getting empty elements from `op.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: @Dai if I remove the DefaultIfEmpty call the query behaves like an outer join instead of a left join, which is my intension.

Comment: @Carorus a `LEFT JOIN` the same thing as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - it's just a shorthand syntax.

Comment: @Carorus This looks like Entity Framework. If you already have a relationship between `Metadata` and `MetadataOptions` defined then you don't need to do joins manually, you can just use `Include()`.